# How can the below 3 select statements be included in a single mySQL view

Tags: mysql, view

Need to create a single view that executes the below 3 select statements

I am able execute them in a SQL editor and get the ratio.

```
select @lag := count(twitter_handles) from handle_impressions where today_impressions > yest_impressions;
select @decay := count(twitter_handles) from handle_impressions where today_impressions < yest_impressions;
select @ratio := @lag/@decay;
```

The intent is to have a single view encapsulating the 3 select statements to return lag, decay and ratio

Comment: You're missing the case when `today_impressions = yest_impressions`. Is this intentional? You might also want to have some type of measure to prevent division by 0.

Comment: good catch, will change one of the comparison to <=. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try writing a single query using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN today_impressions > yest_impressions THEN 1 END) AS lag_val,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN today_impressions < yest_impressions THEN 1 END) AS decay_val,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN today_impressions > yest_impressions THEN 1 END) /
        COUNT(CASE WHEN today_impressions < yest_impressions THEN 1 END) AS ratio
FROM handle_impressions;
```